# How to display selected GridView row in DetailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a aspx page that has a GridView with a datasource of an array of the Client class. I would like to include a DetailsView below the GridView that shows the information of the selected GridView row and allows the user to edite that row. When they are done editing the row, I plan to call the web service to update the row.

Is there an easy way to link the selected GridView row to the DetailsView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a GridView_SelectedIndexChanging event you can use then you can update the datasource for the DetailView. After editing, users can upload the result to call the web service.